# Cups not working in client machine

Tags: server, printing, localhost

I am just trying to make the cups page appear on a client machine. 
I have installed cups via `apt-get install cups`. 
I have installed the cups client via `apt-get install cups cups-client`.

I have edited the `cups.conf.d` file to allow access to the server:

```
Restrict Access to the Server
<Location />
##Order allow,deny
##Allow all
</Location>
```

When I go to the client machine and type `localhost:631/admin`, I receive The Unable To Connect screen...

Any suggestions on what is going wrong?

Comment: 1) A `#` at the beginning of a line in a cups configuration file indicates that  the line has been commented out and will be ignored. Is that what you intended? 2) What file are you editing? On the client or on the server? `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` or something else? 3) Could you please post the full filename and full contents of the file, and specify which computer it's from?

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded from 64-bit XUbuntu 14.04 "Trusty" to the 64-bit XUbuntu 16.04 "Xenial" and then I experienced the same issue.

Here's the command that fixed this for me (run it on the cups **server**):

```
sudo mv /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/cups.path /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/cups.service
```

...then restart your **server** computer, or alternatively run this command:

```
sudo service cupsd restart
```

...and use your **client** machine to check if the problem is gone.

---

- **Now the explanation:**

On *Ubuntu systems, there must be a *cups.**service*** file working as a symlink (a symbolic link) that points to */lib/systemd/system/cups.**path***. In other words, the correct should be this:

> /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/cups.**service** ->
>   /lib/systemd/system/cups.path

However, it seems that the most recent *Ubuntu builds are coming with a misconfiguration that has this:

> /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/cups.**path** ->
>   /lib/systemd/system/cups.path

...which causes the `rc.d` scripts not to work properly at bootup (system initialization / startup).

Renaming the extension of the symlink file from *cups.**path*** to *cups.**service*** (and then restarting the computer or the cups daemon) thus fixes the issue.

---

If the above solution doesn't solve the problem (or if such error is not present in your system), then another possible reason is the `HostnameLookups` parameter is set to `Off` argument instead of `On`. In order to fix it, just run this command on your cups **server** machine:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/HostnameLookups Off/HostnameLookups On/' "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

...and then restart your computer. If you wish to force it to restart, run this command:

```
sudo telinit 6
```

After rebooting the **server**, use your **client** machine to check if the problem is gone.

---

If after all this the problem is still there, remove the cups init script links from your cups **server** machine:

```
sudo update-rc.d cups remove
```

...and then add the links back with their default settings:

```
sudo update-rc.d cups defaults
```

...then restart your **server** computer:

```
sudo telinit 6
```

...and use your **client** machine to check if the problem is gone.

---

If after this the service still isn't loading, maybe the symbolic link to `cpus.service` is missing. In order to fix it, first become **superuser** (run the command below the shell/terminal emulator):

```
sudo su
```

...and then run the supercommand below in order to create the symbolic link and start the service right after:

```
sudo ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/cups.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/cups.service ; systemctl enable cups.service
```